# Why render json: is returning NULL instead of boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why I'm getting `null` instead of **true/false** for **is_read** when calling resource from API?

Offquestion: Could be related to `render json:` internals?

This is the first time when I see this sorcery so please bear with me. Looking for good answer :)

```
$ curl -X GET -H localhost:3000/api/v1/alerts/1/show | python -m json.tool


{
    "body": "Deserunt laboriosam quod consequuntur est dolor cum molestias.",
    "created_at": "2015-03-22T15:02:01.927Z",
    "id": 1,
    "is_read": null,
    "subtitle": "Aspernatur non voluptatem minus qui laudantium molestiae.",
    "title": "Et nemo magni autem similique consequuntur.",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-22T15:02:01.927Z"
}
```

`-i`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Etag: "3232ec2058ffb13db1f9244366fe2ea8"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: c520cabe-6334-4997-956b-d1f21724b80c
X-Runtime: 0.016337
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)
Date: Sun, 22 Mar 2015 15:28:21 GMT
Content-Length: 300
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Rails console:**

```
Alert.find(1)
  Alert Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "alerts".* FROM "alerts"  WHERE "alerts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Alert id: 1, title: "Et nemo magni autem similique consequuntur.", subtitle: "Aspernatur non voluptatem minus qui laudantium mol...", body: "Deserunt laboriosam quod consequuntur est dolor cu...", is_read: false, created_at: "2015-03-22 15:02:01", updated_at: "2015-03-22 15:02:01">
```

And weird thing happens when I call `#to_json`

```
Alert.find(1).to_json
  Alert Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "alerts".* FROM "alerts"  WHERE "alerts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> "{\"id\":1,\"title\":\"Et nemo magni autem similique consequuntur.\",\"subtitle\":\"Aspernatur non voluptatem minus qui laudantium molestiae.\",\"body\":\"Deserunt laboriosam quod consequuntur est dolor cum molestias.\",\"is_read\":null,\"created_at\":\"2015-03-22T15:02:01.927Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-03-22T15:02:01.927Z\"}"
```

It's also happening when is_read is true.

#### More information:

*Rails 4.1.7, Ruby 2.1.2*, Postgresql

**Alert**

```
create_table "alerts", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "subtitle"
  t.text     "body"
  t.boolean  "is_read",    default: false, null: false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**Script used to populate db:**

```
Alert.populate 100 do |alert|
  alert.title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(3)
  alert.subtitle = Faker::Lorem.sentence(3)
  alert.body = Faker::Lorem.sentence(3)
  alert.is_read = false
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def show
  alert = Alert.find(params[:id])
  render json: alert
end
```

[image: PostgreSQL]

**EDIT 26 Mar 2015**

```
irb(main):013:0> Alert.find(1)
  Alert Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "alerts".* FROM "alerts"  WHERE "alerts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Alert id: 1, title: "Test", subtitle: "waaat?", body: "heeeelp", is_read: false, created_at: "2015-03-26 15:49:32", updated_at: "2015-03-26 15:56:51">
irb(main):014:0> a.body
=> "heeeelp"
irb(main):015:0> a.title
=> "Test"
irb(main):016:0> a.is_read
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> a["is_read"]
=> false
irb(main):018:0> a.update_attributes(is_read: true)
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "alerts" SET "is_read" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "alerts"."id" = 1  [["is_read", "t"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-26 15:57:26.645210"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):019:0> a["is_read"]
=> true
```

**Final: it was because there was attr_reader :is_read in the model. Removing that it will result in a correct serialization. Can someone explain this?**

Comment: Can you try `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET localhost:3000/api/v1/alerts/1/show` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Final: it was because there was attr_reader :is_read in the model. Removing that it will result in a correct serialization. Can someone explain this?

ActiveRecord helps map your database fields to methods on your Ruby class by creating a getter method for each attribute, that pulls the value from the internal attribute store (variable.)

When you define `attr_reader :is_read`, which is actually shorthand for:

```
# app/mode/alert.rb    
def is_read
  @is_read
end
```

Your getter method that was handily provided by `ActiveRecord::Base` will be masked by this newly defined method. This can be unexpected, and definitely seem like sorcery at first.

The behaviour of `:attr_reader` is (somewhat sparsely) documented here:

> Creates instance variables *and corresponding methods* that return the value of each instance variable.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader

> But why then it is coming as null? Could be related to render json: internals?

There are two parts to this question.

Firstly, why is the value not there? The answer to this was given above. Your model has masked the ActiveRecord getter method `is_read`, that was poiting to ActiveRecord's internal attribute store, with one pointing to an instance variable `@is_read`. Because you do not assign `@is_read` in your model, `nil` is returned.

Secondly, why is it `null` and not `nil`? The answer to this is, as you hinted at, related to `render: json`. In the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org), you have the following allowed values:

> *string*, *number*, *object*, *array*, true, false, null

To produce a valid JSON response, `render: json` replaces Ruby's `nil`, with JSON's `null`.

So is it safe then to say that you never want to use `attr_reader`, `attr_accessor` et. al. in your models? Not really. These can be used as *virtual*, or transient attributes, that are lost once the object is destroyed. One should keep in mind, though, the interactions with ActiveRecord, to avoid running into seemingly obscure bugs.

Comment: Thank you!. It is clear now what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

From your edit:

```
Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :is_read
end
```

When you define an ActiveRecord model it automatically creates getters and setters for each column in your table. These getters and setters are different than the ones created using attr_accessor, attr_reader, and attr_writer. They access the attributes hash rather than instance variables. Using attr_accessor, attr_reader, or attr_writer will override the getter that ActiveRecord automatically set. If you want 'is_read' to be read only try this:

```
Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :is_read
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the boolean type of active_record is integer type at mysql actually.

But, you can use this gem to customize your response json

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: But why then it is coming as `null` ?

Comment: I know about active model serializers but I don't want to use it for such a small task. I use `postgresql` (so I have boolean values). Even if mysql cannot store boolean values the returned value should be  INT NOT NULL

Comment: the boolean type will return 0 or 1 in normal, I think you should check the value is right in database.

Comment: Thank you @ethan. I've also attached a screenshot on my question. In postgres there are multiple valid values for [boolean](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-boolean.html)